# Download XLS sheet from server to IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xls

How to download a .xls sheet from server and save it in iPhone memory, if spreadsheet is bigger in size then process took place in background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in any method.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki"]; //Your URL here

NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];   

NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Text_file.xls"];  

[dbFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

**I assume that you server doesn't require authentication**

Comment: Thank's , Yaa server not needs any authentication but If XLS sheet is big then process go in Background automativcally .

Comment: You can use thread, also you can organize downloader class separately.